# Rotas no Laravel

Tags: laravel

Ao prefixar o middleware **auth**, conforme abaixo, estou de forma automática implementando também o middleware ***web***?

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'painel', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    //
}
```

Comment: **web.php** é a rota, né ? Não uma Middleware

Comment: na verdade temos vários middleware ou grupos de middleware, sendo que um deles é o **web** conforme pode ser verificado no arquivo Kernel.php, minha dúvida é, ao aplicar o auth também tenho que aplicar o middlewareGroups web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é necessariamente o middleware auth que automaticamente implementa o web. Na verdade, pelo menos no laravel 5.2, de acordo com a documentação o middleware web é implementado automaticamente no arquivo routes.php pelo RouteServiceProvider.

> Keep in mind, the web middleware group is automatically applied to your default routes.php file by the RouteServiceProvider.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware